FC_shell commands only runs the last line in a tcl script
as per title, I am trying to write a tcl script that gives the output of the all_fanout -from $placeholder and sizeof_collection [all_fanout -from $placeholder].
The script looks as follows:
set $placeholder [list xddd xppp xdxx ppxx]
all_fanout -from $placeholder
sizeof_collection [all_fanout -from $placeholder}

After doing source filename.tcl in the fc_shell terminal, the only output is 4, with no sign of the output of all_fanout -from $placeholder.
What seems to be the issue there? Is it just the behaviour of the fc_shell commands?

Is there in fact a shell question here, vs a TCL question? (I'd suggest dropping the shell tag if people who are shell experts but not TCL experts aren't expected to be able to help here).

Now you mentioned it, it is more of a TCL question. But it involves some shell question to a certain extent, as I'm unsure is it the shell commands are causing the problem, or is it just TCL problem.

When you run a Tcl script, the result of the script is the result of the last command executed in the script. If you want any intermediate values, you need to explicitly print them (puts) or to save them and somehow compose them together at the end (maybe with list or dict create).
This is different from interactive use, where the result is printed of every command line (depending on what info complete says about syntactic completeness) that doesn't produce an empty string; empty strings are omitted, and many commands have that as their result.

I see, thanks for the insight! I have tried to do some changes, as per advice, which looks as such:
set $placeholder [list xddd xppp xdxx ppxx]
set xdd [sizeof_collection [all_fanout -from $placeholder]]
puts $xdd
set xpp [all_fanout -from $placeholder]
puts $xpp
In this case, I have obtain the following.
4
_sel9085
So now, did i mess up something for puts under all_fanout, or is it something else... ?
Thanks again Donal!

The set $placeholder .... looks unlikely. In Tcl, $ means "read a variable", not "here is a variable".

Try this:
set $placeholder [list xddd xppp xdxx ppxx]
set c1 [all_fanout -from $placeholder]
puts [get_object_name $c1]
puts [sizeof_collection $c1]

In this EDA tool, command "all_fanout" returns the ID of a collection of objects, not a list of object names. There are commands to handle such collection. For example, "get_object_name" returns the object names in the specified collection. "sizeof_collection" returns the number of objects in the collection.

I forgot about get_object_name  existance, but it works like charm! Thanks for the explanation as well, as now i can put it into a foreach loop and works as well! The old code used to cant run in a foreach loop as well, likely due to as you explained. Thanks again sharvian!

set placeholder [list xddd xppp xdxx ppxx]

foreach a $placeholder {
    set fanout [get_object_name [all_fanout -from $a]]
    set size [sizeof_collection [all_fanout -from $a]]
}

you are trying to get the all_fanout of the elements in the placeholder list and size of it. I am not a FC_shell user but this get_object_name may or may not be required. Otherwise this should work fine.
